# I get an error when building QT6 on windows

Tags: qt, compiler-errors, c++17, g++

I downloaded qt6 source package and I have downloaded all requirements for the installation, but I'm getting this error:

```
PS C:\qt6-dev\src\qt6-build> ..\configure.bat -prefix 'C:\qt6' 
+ cd qtbase
+ C:\qt6-dev\src\qtbase\configure.bat -top-level -prefix C:\qt6 
-- Windows 10 SDK version:
'C:/msys64/ucrt64/bin/cmake.exe' '-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=C:/qt6' '-DQT_QMAKE_TARGET_MKSPEC=win32-g++' '-G' 'Ninja' 'C:/qt6-dev/src'
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 13.1.0
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 13.1.0
-- The ASM compiler identification is GNU
-- Found assembler: C:/msys64/ucrt64/bin/cc.exe
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/msys64/ucrt64/bin/c++.exe - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/msys64/ucrt64/bin/cc.exe - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Configuring submodule 'qtbase'
            -DCMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG=-g
            -DCMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE=-O3 -DNDEBUG
            -DCMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO=-O2 -g -DNDEBUG
            -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG=-g
            -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE=-O3 -DNDEBUG
            -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO=-O2 -g -DNDEBUG
            -DCMAKE_OBJCOPY=C:/msys64/ucrt64/bin/objcopy.exe
            -DCMAKE_C_STANDARD=11
            -DCMAKE_C_STANDARD_REQUIRED=ON
            -DCMAKE_CXX_STANDARD=17
            -DCMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED=ON
            -DCMAKE_MODULE_PATH:STRING=C:/qt6-dev/src/qtbase/cmake/platforms
CMake Error at qtbase/cmake/QtSyncQtHelpers.cmake:243 (message):
  syncqt.cpp failed for module QtCore:

  The syncqt process exited with code Exit code 0xc0000139

   and without any useful output. This can happen if syncqt crashes due to the incompatibilities with the standard C++ library located by either PATH or LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variables. Please make sure that PATH or LD_LIBRARY_PATH don't point to the standard libraries different from the one you use for building Qt.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  qtbase/cmake/QtModuleHelpers.cmake:873 (qt_internal_target_sync_headers)
  qtbase/cmake/QtScopeFinalizerHelpers.cmake:24:EVAL:1 (qt_finalize_module)
  qtbase/src/corelib/CMakeLists.txt:DEFERRED
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
CMake Error at C:/qt6-dev/src/qtbase/cmake/QtProcessConfigureArgs.cmake:995 (message):
  CMake exited with code 1.
```

What's going on and how to solve this problem?

Comment: I suspect msys may be the culprit here. Did you follow the Qt instructions for preparing msys2? https://wiki.qt.io/MSYS2#Prepare_MSYS2_for_Qt_related_build_development_environment

Answer (score 0):

This was fixed for me by running the configure step as an admin.

```
sudo /<PATH_TO_CONFIGFURE_FILE
```